# Test Application behaviour when limited Memory

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management

I am working on a winform application. I want to test my application behavior when there is lack of memory on system.

My application processes large number of images and show in listview. I have implemented Virtual mode and other techniques to minimize memory. I can run my application fine in my system and don't find any issue related to memory when observing through "Task Manager". However my client reported me "out of memory" issue, when running application (he tested on 1gb system).

So I want to know whether there is tool or technique which I can use to test my application in limited memory (say, I want to my application behave same as it behave in system with 1gb memory)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jon Hanna's answer in this thread:

[How to simulate low memory for .net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466361/how-to-simulate-low-memory-for-net-application)

The important thing to note is that each process gets its own Virtual Memory space, so to simulate running low on your own Virtual Memory you should allocate some unused filler memory (as Jon suggests).